# List Buffer Prepend: error: value ++=: is not a member of Seq[Int]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm getting an error that ListBuffer doesn't have a method ++=: for appending. Even thought, it's in the doc.

```
scala> val lb = new ListBuffer[Int]
lb: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer()

scala> lb ++= Seq(1,2,3)
res20: lb.type = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> lb ++=: Seq(4,5)
<console>:10: error: value ++=: is not a member of Seq[Int]
              lb ++=: Seq(4,5)
```

From doc:

```
def ++=:(xs: TraversableOnce[A]): ListBuffer.this.type
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used in the infix position, methods ending with a `:` are right-associative.
You can either call the method on `lb` using a `.`, or reverse the arguments :

```
scala> lb.++=:(Seq(4,5))
res3: lb.type = ListBuffer(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)

scala> Seq(7,6,8) ++=: lb
res4: lb.type = ListBuffer(7, 6, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the colon means that the function is called on the object to the right

try

```
Seq(4, 5) ++=: lb
```